# How to fix overlapping VBox children in a canvas?

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I have multiple HBoxes inside a VBox inside a canvas like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*">
<mx:Canvas  width="600" height="500">
        <mx:VBox height="100%" left="10" right="10">
        <mx:HBox width="100%" >
        <mx:VBox width="48%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="left">
        <mx:Label text="Label" />

        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox width="48%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="left">
        <mx:Label text="Label" />
        <mx:HBox width="100%">
            <mx:VBox width="48%">   
                <mx:Label text="Label" />
                <mx:ComboBox />
            </mx:VBox>

        </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>


        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:VBox>
            <mx:HBox>
                <mx:Label text="Label" />
                <mx:Label text="Label" />
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:Label text="Label" />
            <mx:ComboBox/>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox>
        <mx:VBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
        includeInLayout="false" >
        <mx:Label text="Label"  />

        </mx:VBox>
        <mx:VBox>
        <mx:HBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            includeInLayout="false"
            >
            <mx:VBox >
                    <mx:Label text="Text" />
                    <mx:ComboBox />
            </mx:VBox>
            <mx:VBox>
                    <mx:Label text="Label" />
                    <mx:ComboBox />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
            includeInLayout="false"
            >
            <mx:VBox>
                <mx:Label text="Label:"/>
                <mx:ComboBox />
            </mx:VBox>
            <mx:VBox>
                <mx:Label text="Label: "/>
                <mx:ComboBox   />
            </mx:VBox>
        </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:HBox >
            <mx:Label text="Label:" />
            <mx:CheckBox />
        </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

The last child in the VBox is overlapping with other components. **How do you prevent children of a VBox in a Canvas from overlapping? How do you debug this situation?**

I have tried the following:

- Removing percent based sizing
- IncludeInLayout = true

Sceenshot - Label and Checkbox Overlapping:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of using includeInLayout="false" anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with the information provided, but the two questions that come to mind first are:

1. Is your VBox height greater than the sum of the heights of its children?
2. Have you set the verticalGap property on the VBox? verticalGap determines vertical spacing between children.

Comment: 1. The height is 100%.
2. I've tried setting this to zero.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this (AIR app) and it looks alright to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">


    <mx:Canvas height="100%" width="100%"
      borderStyle="solid" 
      backgroundColor="0x0000ff">

      <mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%">

        <mx:VBox backgroundColor="0xff0000" height="50%" width="100%">
            <mx:HBox backgroundColor="0x000000" height="50%" width="50%"/>
            <mx:HBox backgroundColor="0xffffff" height="50%" width="50%"/>
            <mx:HBox backgroundColor="0x00ffff" height="50%" width="50%"/>
        </mx:VBox>

    <mx:HBox height="50%" width="100%" 
        backgroundColor="0xff0000" backgroundAlpha="0.5" 
        borderColor="0x000000" borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="1"/>

    </mx:VBox>          

    </mx:Canvas>



</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by making the includeInLayout property of some of these components the same conditional used by their visible property.

Not sure what caused the issue though.